# Can't seem to set a bounty on my own question, after 2 days, with 65 rep

Tags: support

Should I be able to set a bounty on a [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90469/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-extend-on-a-non-object) asked 2 days ago if I have 65 rep?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly you need a reputation of 75 or higher to set a bounty.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties

Answer (score 1):

It seems you've [bountied another post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89720/steps-to-enable-e-commerce-in-brochure-website) which **lowered your rep below the 75 point threshold**.

It may seem counter-intuitive but permissions are revoked if you don't meet the point threshold necessary. You must maintain your reputation to continue to enjoy certain site features.

See here for other permissions earned at various levels: https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/